# How do I numerically compute the $L^1$ norm of the Fourier transform of a bump function?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, warning-messages, fourier-analysis

I'm trying to compute the following. Let $$f(t) := \exp\left(\frac{1}{t^2 - 1}\right)1_{-1 < t < 1}.$$ This function looks like (it's the standard example of the bump function on Wikipedia).

[image: bump]

Next, consider the Fourier transform of $f$ given by $$\widehat{f}(\xi) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t)e^{-i t\omega}\, dt.$$ My question is, how does one numerically compute the integral $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|\widehat{f}(\omega)|\, d\omega?$$

I'm doing this via the commands

```
   Needs["FourierSeries`"]
   f[t_] = Piecewise[{{Exp[1/(t^2 - 1)], -1 < t < 1}}]
   NIntegrate[Abs[NFourierTransform[f[t], t, ω]], {ω, -Infinity,Infinity}]
```

This outputs

```
NIntegrate::ncvb:
  NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 9 recursive bisections in ω near {ω} = {12.4765}. NIntegrate obtained 1.1329578878244777` and 0.000052199655872313335` for the integral and error estimates.
```

Is there a way to get rid of this issue?

Comment: The warning goes away if you add the option `PrecisionGoal -> 4`, because the numbers in the message imply four digits of precision.  If that is not accurate enough, you can set `MaxRecursion -> 20` higher.  (I believe the problem is that it is an oscillatory integral, but the function is numerical, perhaps limiting `NIntegrate` from using a more sophisticated strategy.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Three methods:

All simplify the problem by using the even symmetry of the transform to change the interval to `{0, Infinity}`, which saves some work for `NIntegrate[]`.  (`NIntegrate[]` would do this automatically, if it could determine the integrand was symmetric.)

#### 1. `PrecisionGoal -> 4`

```
2 * NIntegrate[
   Abs[NFourierTransform[f[t], t, ω]], {ω, 0, Infinity},
    PrecisionGoal -> 4] // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {28.6487, 1.13297} *)
```

#### 2. `MaxRecursion -> 20`

```
2 * NIntegrate[
   Abs[NFourierTransform[f[t], t, ω]], {ω, 0, Infinity},
    MaxRecursion -> 20] // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {86.8169, 1.13296}  *)
```

#### 3. Feed zeros to `NIntegrate[]` as singular points.

The derivative is undefined at the zeros of `f[t]`, so they are "weak" singularities.  Again, if `NIntegrate[]` could find them, it could adjust itself, but `f[t]` essentially behaves like a numerical black box.

```
{poszeros} = 
   Last@Reap@
     NDSolve[{x'[ω] == Sin[ω], x[0] == 0., 
       WhenEvent[Re@NFourierTransform[f[t], t, ω] == 0, 
        Sow[ω]]}, x, {ω, 0, 200}, 
      Method -> "Extrapolation", MaxStepSize -> 3]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {29.1027, Null}  *)

2 * NIntegrate[
   Abs[NFourierTransform[f[t], t, ω]], {ω, 0, 
    Sequence @@ Sort[poszeros], Infinity}] // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {28.8482, 1.13296}  *)
```

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is to use [`NDSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolve) to create a [`FourierTransform`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FourierTransform) function, and then use [`NDSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolve) again to integrate the function. To do this, first note that the function is even, so that the [`FourierTransform`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FourierTransform) can be converted to a [`FourierCosTransform`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FourierCosTransform). This is useful because the end point is problematic for [`NDSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolve). So, here is a [`Fourier`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Fourier) transform interpolating function:

```
ft = NDSolveValue[
    {D[FT[t, ω], t] == Sqrt[2/π] Piecewise[{{Exp[1/(t^2-1)], t<1}}] Cos[t ω], FT[0, ω]==0}, 
    FT[1, ω], 
    {t, 0, 1}, 
    {ω, -500, 500}, 
    MaxStepFraction->.0005,
    AccuracyGoal->10
]; //AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.550217, Null}

I used a cutoff of $\left| \omega \right| <500$ for the frequency domain. Now, we could use [`NIntegrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NIntegrate) to compute the $L^1$ norm, but this is rather slow. It is much faster to use [`NDSolveValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolveValue) again:

```
NDSolveValue[{g'[ω] == 2 Abs @ ft, g[0] == 0}, g[500], {ω, 0, 500}] //AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.291507, 1.13296}

in good agreement with @MichaelE2's answer.